# Spring boot kafka error: app fail to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EVUy.png)

error found in running app.

```
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: 1) Please show your error as text, not images 2) Timed out... Is kafka actually running on localhost? How did you start it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.